# Верстка колончатого графика

Tags: canvas, javascript, html, css, вёрстка

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с версткой.
Есть вот такая простенькая страница. На странице выводятся 4 колонки разной высоты, "приклеенные" к низу графика. У каждого div'а с помощью php задается высота и отступ сверху. Все работает прекрасно, но... при изменении ширины .graf столбики начинают ползать вверх-вниз. Как побороть этот недостаток?
И вопрос вдогонку: целесообразно ли в таких случаях подключать canvas?

```
<!doctype html>  
<html>  
<head><title></title>  
<style type="text/css">  
.graf{  
    width: 260px;  
    height: 260px;  
    padding: 20px;  
}  
.graf .graf_axes{  
    position: relative;  
    width: 100%;  
    height: 100%;  
    border: 1px #000 solid;  
    border-top: none;  
    border-right: none;  
    padding: 0 0 1px;  
}  
.graf .graf_axes .col{  
    display: inline-block;  
    float: left;  
    margin: 0 15px;  
    width: 30px;  
    border: 1px #000 solid;  
    border-bottom: none;  
}  
.graf .graf_axes .col1{background: #f00}  
.graf .graf_axes .col2{background: #0f0}  
.graf .graf_axes .col3{background: #00f}  
.graf .graf_axes .col4{background: #f80}  
</style>  
</head>  
<body>

<div class="graf">  
    <div class="graf_axes">  
        <div class="col col1" style="height:30%;margin-top:70%;">30%</div>  
        <div class="col col2" style="height:50%;margin-top:50%;">50%</div>  
        <div class="col col3" style="height:90%;margin-top:10%;">90%</div>  
        <div class="col col4" style="height:100%;margin-top:0%;">100%</div>  
    </div>  
</div>

</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот готовый кроссбраузерный вариант.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <style type="text/css">
   .graf {
    height: 260px;
    width: 260px;
    padding: 20px;
   }
   
   .graf_axes {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
   }

   .col {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: none;
    width: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
   }

   .col1 {
    background: #f00;
    height: 30%;
    left: 20px;
   }

   .col2 {
    background: #0f0;
    height: 50%;
    left: 65px;
   }

   .col3 {
    background: #00f;
    height: 90%;
    left: 110px;
   }

   .col4 {
    background: #f80;
    height: 100%;
    left: 155px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="graf">
   <div class="graf_axes">
    <div class="col col1">30%</div>
    <div class="col col2">50%</div>
    <div class="col col3">90%</div>
    <div class="col col4">100%</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Колонки тянутся по высоте в зависимости от высоты .graf, единственное, что ширина между колонками регулируется через абсолютное положение от левого края родительского блока и никак не меняется при изменении ширины .graf, если для Вас это не критично (а как видно из предложенного Вами варианта, ширина между колонками задается в пикселях, не в процентах), то это готовый вариант, если нужно чтобы и расстояние между колонками изменялось пропорционально, то нужно покопаться.

Answer (score 1):

Делайте так:

```
<!doctype html>  
<html>  
<head><title></title>  
<style type="text/css">  
.graf{  
    width: 260px;  
    height: 260px;  
    padding: 20px;  
}  
.graf .graf_axes{  
    position: relative;  
    width: 100%;  
    height: 100%;  
    border: 1px #000 solid;  
    border-top: none;  
    border-right: none;  
    padding: 0 0 1px;  
    overflow: hidden;
}  
.graf .graf_axes .col{  
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;  
    float: left;  
    margin: 0 15px;  
    width: 30px;  
    border: 1px #000 solid;  
    border-bottom: none;  
}  
.graf .graf_axes .col1{background: #f00}  
.graf .graf_axes .col2{background: #0f0}  
.graf .graf_axes .col3{background: #00f}  
.graf .graf_axes .col4{background: #f80}  
</style>  
</head>  
<body>

<div class="graf">  
    <div class="graf_axes">  
        <div class="col col1" style="margin-top:70%;">30%</div>  
        <div class="col col2" style="margin-top:50%;">50%</div>  
        <div class="col col3" style="margin-top:10%;">90%</div>  
        <div class="col col4" style="margin-top:0%;">100%</div>  
    </div>  
</div>

</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: К сожалению, при увеличении ширины .graf колонки по-прежнему уползают вниз. Только теперь их не видно).

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте сами блоки никуда не двигать, а двигать фон этих блоков. то бишь высота у блоков будет 100% всегда, а вот background-position-y будет варьироваться, ну и соответственно минус этого способа в том, что надо использовать картинки

Comment: Интересный подход, но у фона по идее должен стоять background-repeat: repeat;, а у колонок - скругленные уголки.

Comment: картинки проще делать вашего 100% размера(260px  в вашем случае) и не надо повторений, а кругляшки уже по вкусу.

Answer (score 0):

Ну тогда сделайте так:

```
<!doctype html>  
<html>  
<head><title></title>  
<style type="text/css">  
.col {
    margin: 0 15px;
    width: 30px;  
    border: 1px #000 solid;  
    border-bottom: 0px;  
    font-size: 10px;
}  
.col1{background: #f00}  
.col2{background: #0f0}  
.col3{background: #00f}  
.col4{background: #f80}

.tbl {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
.tbl td {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
</style>  
</head>  
<body>

<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 class="tbl">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="col col1" style="height:30%;">30%</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="col col2" style="height:50%;">50%</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="col col3" style="height:70%;">70%</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="col col4" style="height:90%;">90%</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Из всех браузеров этот код "съел" только Хром. Но все равно спасибо за попытку).

Comment: Только под хромом и смотрел :)

Answer (score 0):

В общем, после тестов выяснилось, что margin-top в процентах считается от ширины(!) родительского контейнера. Почему - сказать не могу, но, видимо, придется переписывать программную часть, задавая высоту элементов в пикселях в коде, а не стилях.
Эх, хотелось красиво, а получилось как всегда.

Comment: Потому что так в стандарте прописано. Подозреваю, что чтобы запись типа `margin: 5%` давала равные отступы со всех сторон.

Answer (score 0):

ещё можете попробовать сделать сразу n-ное кол-во столбцов, и уже в этих столбцах делать графы:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="column"><div class="graf">30%</div></div>
  <div class="column"><div class="graf">50%</div></div>
  <div class="column"><div class="graf">100%</div></div>
  <div class="column"><div class="graf">10%</div></div>
</div>
```

столбцы имеют 100% высоту

Answer (score 0):

DStereo, спасибо, ваш ответ навел меня на правильный вариант:

```
<!doctype html>  
<html>  
<head><title></title>  
<style type="text/css">  
.graf{  
    width: 460px;  
    height: 260px;  
    padding: 20px;  
}  
.graf .graf_axes{  
    position: relative;  
    width: 100%;  
    height: 100%;  
    border: 1px #000 solid;  
    border-top: none;  
    border-right: none;  
}  
.graf .graf_axes .col{  
    height: 100%;  
    display: inline-block;  
    float: left;  
    margin: -1px 15px 0;  
    width: 30px;  
    border: 1px #000 solid;  
    border-bottom: none;  
    position: relative;  
}  
.graf .graf_axes .col1{background: #f00}  
.graf .graf_axes .col2{background: #0f0}  
.graf .graf_axes .col3{background: #00f}  
.graf .graf_axes .col4{background: #f80}  
</style>  
</head>  
<body>

<div class="graf">  
    <div class="graf_axes">  
        <div class="col col1" style="height:30%;top:70%;">30%</div>  
        <div class="col col2" style="height:50%;top:50%;">50%</div>  
        <div class="col col3" style="height:90%;top:10%;">90%</div>  
        <div class="col col4" style="height:100%;top:0%;">100%</div>  
        <div class="col col1" style="height:55%;top:45%;">55%</div>  
    </div>  
</div>

</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> margin-top:70%;
> ```

В этом проблема - он же от ширины считается, а не от высоты.

А делать надо так (при желании раскрасить ещё):

```css
.chart {
  height: 10em; /* any value */
}

.chart .col {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart">  
  <div class="col" style="height:30%;">30%</div>  
  <div class="col" style="height:50%;">50%</div>  
  <div class="col" style="height:90%;">90%</div>  
  <div class="col" style="height:100%;">100%</div>  
  <div class="col" style="height:55%;">55%</div>  
</div>
```